# How to set a command block to test for the time and change it?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

I've been building up villages on my server, and I'd really like to not have to watch for zombie sieges. I'd like to set up a command block to detect when it is almost midnight, and then skip midnight. The old methods I've found on here aren't working as the /stats command has been removed.

Anyone know how I can do this? I'm running 1.15.2

Comment: My answer [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/368606/243753) describes how to skip night, so you can just change the tick at which it activates

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Daylight_Detector) you could use an inverted daylight sensor. An inverted one will output a signal strength of 15 minus the current light level. At midnight that's a signal strength of 11 so if you run a redstone line from an inverted daylight sensor for 10 blocks (so that it triggers shortly before midnight) and place a command block after it set to advance the time by a certain amount when it receives a signal you can skip midnight or as much time as you want based on how much time you say to advance in the command block.